# Unexpected Checkbox Behavior in Bootstrap 5 Accordion

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, bootstrap-5, accordion

I have a selection of checkbox items that I want to put into a Bootstrap 5 accordian element. The checkbox items work fine in the open (checking the boxes adds items to an array; unchecking them removes items from the array), but when I place them in an accordian element, they do not work (checking the boxes does nothing; unchecking them adds items to the array).

Here's the code by itself.

```
<form class = "list">
  <div class="form-check" ng-repeat="x in people_list">
    <a id="{{x.initial}}"></a>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id={{x.id}} ng-click="clickPeople(x.id, x.names)" ng-checked="checkall" ng-model="x.Selected">
    <label class="form-check-label" for={{x.id}}>{{x.names}} ({{x.tag_link_count}})</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's the code inserted into an accordian element.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Select Tags to Search For
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <form class = "list">
          <div class="form-check" ng-repeat="x in tags">
        <a id="{{x.initial}}"></a>
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id={{x.id}} ng-click="clickPeople(x.id, x.names)" ng-checked="checkall" ng-model="x.Selected">
          <label class="form-check-label" for={{x.id}}>{{x.names}} ({{x.tag_link_count}})</label>
      </div>
    </form>                       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dbqandersons/pen/mdoeBJK) contains both working and non-working examples of my checkboxes (my JSFiddle account seems to be having issues).

I have seen references in answers to similar issues that talk about stopping click event propagation, but I can't wrap my mind about how to fix my problems using the examples I've found.  Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Cheers, Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so these are the list of changes made.

1. The click event, I am passing the entire object `x` and maintaining the selected property in the name `Selected`, then using this I am validating the item if its checked or not.
2. The click event, has a typo where you are looking for `name` property, but in the object its has it defined as `names`, so I changed the JS code to use `names`!
3. Finally I removed the code outside accordion which is causing some wierd scrolling, there should be only one element with a unique ID.

Please find below a working example!

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
var nonYearList = [];
var yearList = [];
var peopleList = [];
var eventList = [];
var holidayList = [];
var otherList = [];
var tagNameList = [];
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.tags = [{
      "id": 2,
      "names": "Clarence Gansemer",
      "type": "2",
      "tag_link_count": "1",
      "initial": "C"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "names": "Dave Anderson",
      "type": "2",
      "tag_link_count": "1",
      "initial": "D"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "names": "Dorothy Strong, Dorothy Gansemer",
      "type": "2",
      "tag_link_count": "2",
      "initial": "D"
    }
  ]
  $scope.clickPeople = function(item) {
    item.Selected = !item.Selected;
    if (item.Selected) {
      tagNameList.push(item.names)
      $scope.tag_names = tagNameList;
    } else {
      var spot = nonYearList.indexOf(item.id);
      if (spot != -1) {
        nonYearList.splice(spot, 1);
      }
      var spot2 = peopleList.indexOf(item.id);
      if (spot2 != -1) {
        peopleList.splice(spot2, 1);
      }
      var spot3 = tagNameList.indexOf(item.names);
      if (spot3 != -1) {
        tagNameList.splice(spot3, 1);
      }

    }

  }

});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>RBT - Tag Search</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <br><br>
  <h4>Checkboxes do not work inside accordion (checked names are not added to Selected Names list (unless they are checked and then un-checked))</h4>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Select Tags to Search For
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <form class="list">
            <div class="form-check" ng-repeat="x in tags">
              <a id="{{x.initial}}"></a>
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id={{x.id}} ng-click="clickPeople(x)" ng-checked="x.Selected" ng-model="x.Selected">
              <label class="form-check-label" for={{x.id}}>{{x.names}} ({{x.tag_link_count}})</label>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br>
    <h4>Selected Names</h4>
    <div ng-repeat="name in tag_names"><span style="margin-left:25px;margin-right:5px" class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary"> </span>&ensp;{{name.replace('Unknown','Unknown Year')}}</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Naren.  I modified the code on my dev site and things are looking and behaving as expected.  Cheers, Bill.